# Cannot load static css

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

started coding a couple of months ago and run into a problem I didn't find anything online. I have the following http requests

```
app.get("/courses", async (req, res) => {
  const courses = await Course.find({});
  res.render("courses/index", { courses, topic: "Μαθήματα" });
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("courses/about", { topic: "Πληροφορίες" });
});

app.get("/courses/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const course = await Course.findById(id);
  return res.render("courses/show", { course, topic: course.title });
});
```

All of the rendered templates are in the same folder but when I try to render something from /courses/:id it can't find the appropriate css and js files. The problem appears only when I use /courses/something else. If I try the same thing with just /:id it loads fine, else I get [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TukKR.png).

The paths I have in my include files are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/footer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/navbar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/coursesIndex.css" />
```

I tried a ton of different possible paths by didn't have any luck. Thank you for your time

Comment: `href="/static/[...]` - you will need the trailing slash I reckon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try prefixing a `/` before the static paths, as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/footer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/navbar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/coursesIndex.css" />
```

It might work, because, the other 2 routes are root level routes. So, when rendered, browser would look for `static/stylesheets/...` in the root directory. So, it worked.
But, when you rendered the same on `/courses/:id` path, the browser would look for `static/stylesheets/...` inside `/courses/:id`(actual would be like `/courses/1`, for example). That directory(`1` in the example) does not exists in your root directory.

So, if you use absolute paths(these are the paths that starts with `/`), browser would look for them from the `root` of your website always. So, this would work.